# How can I permanently set cursor speed in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, cursor

I've been using the following command to set my mouse cursor speed; however, upon restart, it just goes back to the default speed. How can I make my adjustment permanent?

TIA!

```
xinput set-prop 9 258 .3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these commands should do the trick:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' | sudo tee /bin/cursorspeed
echo 'xinput set-prop 9 258 .3' | sudo tee -a /bin/cursorspeed
sudo chmod +x /bin/cursorspeed
```

Finally, search for the "startup applications" app.

Click <kbd>add</kbd> and fill in the name: **cursorspeed**, command: **cursorspeed**, and you can leave comment blank or add a comment.

Then, click <kbd>close</kbd> and it should apply next time you login automatically.

To explain, this creates a bash script named cursorspeed containing the command you use to set the mousespeed. Using startup applications, you can set the script to execute at startup.