# Mouse is too slow, no mouse acceleration

Tags: mouse-pointer

I upgraded from 16.04 to 19.04. Now my mouse pointer speed is way slower, I set it to maximum speed but it's still slow. This is unworkable as I have three screens and I can't move the mouse pointer over three screens without using a lot more space than my mouse mat. I use standard Ubuntu 19.04, that's with gnome3 I think. I asked this question before, when I upgraded to 18.04, but I ended up going back to 16.04. With tweak tools, I set acceleration to "adaptive", which seems to be the fastest of the three options. But it's still slow.

How do I increase mouse acceleration by at least a factor 10? Like I had in 16.04?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Search here for "mouse speed" or "mouse acceleration"  and your DE (GNOME3 / KDE / etc).  An answer for your question likely already exists.

Comment: Gnome. The issue has existed for a number of years now. The reason it's important to me is that larger mouse movements give you carpal tunnel syndrome.

Comment: Possibly the update failed to properly update your mouse driver? Do you have a non-standard mouse? Check 'Additional Drivers'?

Comment: see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/589413/how-can-i-permanently-set-cursor-speed-in-gnome-3 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/765738/how-can-i-increase-the-speed-of-the-cursor-in-gnome-terminal

Comment: also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065542/how-to-disable-mouse-acceleration-on-ubuntu-18-04/1065543#1065543

Comment: I tried dconf-editor. Didn't help.

Comment: It is mouse pointer acceleration I'm looking for. Ubuntu 16.04 has a slider for that. 19.04 doesn't.